# CommonJS module doesn't set the values for variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, synchronous, commonjs

My `init()` function in the main file works just fine, but when I put in into a separate module and require it, apparently it stops working. I get this error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'AudioParam': The provided float value is non-finite.
```

It looks like it might be its sync problem? How can I get around this?

```
//init.js file
var initt = function () {
  octaveNumber = document.getElementById("octaveNum");
  audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
  osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  volume = audioCtx.createGain();
  filter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
  osc.connect(filter);
  volume.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  booleanVal = false;
  osc.frequency.value = dial.value
  osc.start();
  gainDisplay.innerHTML = gainSlider.value;
  noteSetOscFreq()
  octaveUpClick()
  octaveDownClick()
  waveFormSelector()
}

module.exports = initt;
```

Main js file:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("presetsArr") {
  messages();
```

But when I don't use module and just put the same initt function in the If statement, it works just fine. do I need to require my main jsfile in the module if the module is dependent on variables in main js file? Like I call other function in my initt() module. Is it good practice? It's my first time using module system.